# How to define a global and absolute path for a QML application?

Tags: qt, qml

In a  QML application I'm working one I have templates components files (stored in *Templates*) that I use in my screens files (stored in *Screens*). The folder structure is like this :

```
.
├── Templates/
│   ├── Buttons/
│   │   ├── ExampleButton.qml //reusable button
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── Text/
│   │   └── ExampleText.qml //reusable text
│   └── ...
└── Screens/
    ├── Menu1/
    │   ├── Menu1_Screen1.qml
    │   ├── Menu1_Screen2.qml
    │   └── Menu1_Screen2/ (sub menu with list of sub screens you can access)
    │       ├── Menu1_Screen2_A.qml
    │       ├── Menu1_Screen2_B.qml //screen that uses ExampleButton.qml
    │       └── ...
    └── Menu2/
        └── ...
```

When I want to include a template folder in a screen to use its templates, I do it with a relative path which makes the header of my QML file look like this :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import "../../../../../Templates/Buttons"
import "../../../../../Templates/Text"
import "../../../../../Templates/Pages"
import "../../../../../Templates/Miscellaneous"
```

**Is there a classy way to define a global and absolute path to *Templates* and use it in my import statement like this ?** (without having to use qmldir and define the content of every directory)

```
import "{$Templates}/Buttons"
```

Comment: You can use `qrc:/` to avoid rewriting the `../../../..` part, but for a better solution, using `qmldir` is indeed best practice. Also, in Qt 6, you can use [`qt_add_qml_module`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-qml-module.html) to automate the generation of the `qmldir` file (if you are using Qt 6.\*.\*).